# Rendering content with HTML tags in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, html, ractivejs

I'm trying to include HTML tags in data rendered by Ractive.js (to auto-subscript chemical symbols, in case anyone cares), but Ractive just inserts the text rather than creating new DOM elements.

A minimal test case, adapted from the [60-second setup guide](http://www.ractivejs.org/60-second-setup):

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
</script>

<script type="text/javscript">
    var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'container',

    template: '#template',

    data: { name: '<b>world</b>' }
});
```

As you can see in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7JLL/), the result is `Hello, <b>world</b>` rather than the expected "Hello, **world**"

I'm guessing this is to do with the way Ractive handles expressions.. but I'm not yet at the point where the source makes much sense.

Any thoughts on how I could get the intended behaviour?

Comment: The JSFiddle does not render as expected for these browsers tried today. Why?  Microsoft Edge 44.17754.1.0 and Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! You can use the triple-stache:

```
<p>Hello, {{{name}}}!</p>
```

In traditional Mustache, this means 'don't escape the value of `name`'. Translated to Ractive, it means 'insert the contents as HTML rather than text.

**Be aware** that the HTML is not sanitised before insertion, so if `name` came from user input there's potential for XSS and other nasties: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/4jBC8/.

Comment: Curse my poor reading comprehension. This worked perfectly, thank you.